# C++: How to get the MSB (Most-Significant Bit) of a Bitset (using bitwise operators)?

Tags: c++, bitset

I am trying to convert a decimal number to a bitset of length `27` and then retrieve the MSB (left-most bit) from that bitset using bitwise operators. For example, the number `67108865` is expressed as `100000000000000000000000001` and the MSB is `1`. Another example is the number `1` which is expressed as `000000000000000000000000001` and the MSB is `0`.

Below is my C++ code:

```
unsigned int value = 67108865;
bitset<27> bs(value);
int most_significant_bit = bs >> (sizeof(value)*8 - 1) & 1;
cout << most_significant_bit << endl;
```

However, I receive the following error:

> error: no match for ‘operator&’ (operand types are ‘std::bitset<27>’
>   and ‘int’)    int most_significant_bit = bs >> (sizeof(value)*8 - 1) &
>   1;

How would I retrieve the MSB using bitwise operators?

Comment: Love my ARM chip's `clz` for this type of work (Count Leading Zeros - usually compilers have a intrinsics for this as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `operator[]` to get the most significant bit.

```
bitset<27> bs(value);
int ms_bit = bs[bs.size()-1];
```

Comment: Is there anyway to retrieve the MSB from the bitset using just bit-wise operators?

Comment: @JustinTrudeau Why would you want to do such a thing when it's built in?

Comment: The whole point of `bitset` is to abstract away the bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2):

This would get you the most significant bit:

```
auto msb = bs[bs.size()-1];
```

To do it using bitwise operators you need to first convert the bitset to an `unsigned long` using [`to_ulong()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong) or `unsigned long long` using [`to_ullong()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong):

```
auto msb = bs.to_ulong() >> (bs.size() - 1);
```